# Is "cosas que [infinitive]" a special construction?

Tags: gramática

**English**

A friend asked me today if this phrase was a special construction or if it had a name:

> Tengo una misión que cumplir

The construction being `[noun] que [infinitive]`. Now, I coudn't really tell him if it had a special name or if there was anything special about it. I thought about it for a second and figured it could be a simple `tener que` contruction with a different word placement for stylistic purposes. Would that be accurate?

**Español**

Un mi amigo me preguntó hoy si esta frase tenía una construcción especial o si tenía un nombre:

> Tengo una misión que cumplir

La construcción sería entonces `[sustantivo] que [infinitivo]`. No supe decirle si la construcción tenía un nombre o algo de especial. Después de pensarlo por unos momentos y deduje que podría ser una construcción de `tener que` con un posicionamiento de palabras distinto. ¿Sería eso acertado?

---

Another possible scenario (could it be about emphasizing something?)/otro escenario posible (tendrá que ver con darle énfasis a algo?):

> -¿No quieres a comer, amiga?
>   -¡No puedo! Tengo reportes que revisar, informes que imprimir y cartas que redactar. ¡Ahh, estrés!

Comment: Si no estoy mal, se llama _perífrasis verbal_.

Comment: @David No, una perífrasis es una construcción con dos verbos. Si variamos ligeramente el ejemplo, en *tengo que cumplir una misión*, *tengo que cumplir* sí sería una perífrasis, pero esto es un caso diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### English

It's a **passive relative infinitive clause**, using the RAE's terminology.

It's relative, as it's introduced by a relative *que* (this also, in effect, makes it an adjectival clause).  It's passive, because noun that comes before it is the one that is to be acted upon by the verb (*misión is to be *cumplida*, rather than to *cumplir* something else).  It's infintival because, well, it uses the infinitive :-) You can read about this in the *Gramática 26.12* where it lists some of the restrictions for its use (indefinite antecedent, etc).

In some cases, you can switch out *a* or *para* in these cases as well (*Gramática* 26.6l), though that does change its interpretation to a nomininalized infinitive.

It does not come from the *tener que* or *haber que* periphrases as evidenced by these two sentences that I think most people would agree are not identical in meaning:

- tengo que comer mucha comida <sub>*(doctor says I'm underweight)*</sub>
- tengo mucha comida que comer <sub>*(I've got —possession— food that ought to be eaten)*</sub>

The last's infinitive can have subject bestowed upon it.<sup>1</sup>  As written, it will normally be interpreted as *tengo mucha comida que comer<sub>(yo)</sub>*, but let's say I'm hosting a dinner party.  The subject is now more likely nosotros: *tengo mucha comida que comer<sub>(nosotros)</sub>* (that is: the food is here for all of us to eat).

---

<sup>1.  Contrary to popular belief, infinitives can in many situations have a subject, however because the infinitive does not conjugate and subjects are often implied, it's harder to notice.</sup>

### Castellano

Se llama un **infinitivo de cláusa subordinada con interpretación pasiva** según la terminología de la RAE.

Es de una cláusa subordinada porque se introduce con el pronombre relativo *que* (por lo tanto, también tiene función adjetival).  Tiene interpretación pasiva porque el sustantivo que le antecede es el complemento directo del verbo (es decir, es que la misión *es (será) cumplida*, en vez de que *cumple* otra cosa).  Es infinitivo por razones obvias.  Puedes leer más de ello en la *Gramática 26.12* que también pormenoriza algunas de las restricciones de uso (antecedente indefinidos, etcétera)

En algunos casos, puedes cambiar el *que* por un *a* o *para* (Gramática 26.6l) pero en tal caso la interpretación sintáctica muda a un infinitivo nominal (o tal vez adjetival).

Esta construcción no viene de los peráfrasis *tener que* y *haber que*, que se evidencia con estas dos oraciones que, creo, la mayoría de los hablantes estarían de acuerdo que no son iguales en sentido:

- tengo que comer mucha comida <sub>*la médica me dice que soy demasiado flaco*</sub>
- tengo mucha comida que comer <sub>*tengo —poseo— comida para la consumición*</sub>

Al infinitivo de la segunda se le puede conceder un sujeto.<sup>1</sup>  Tal y como está escrito, normalmente se lo interpretará como *tengo mucha comida que comer<sub>(yo)</sub>*, pero digamos que el contexto es que doy una fiesta.  Ahora el sujeto probablemente es *nosotros*: *tengo mucha comida que comer<sub>(nosotros)</sub>* (es decir: la comida es para la consumición nuestra).

---

<sup>1.  Hay muchos que piensan que el infinitivo no puede tener sujeto porque no flexiona, pero la verdad es que sí lo puede tener (tanto explícito como implícito), pero es más difícil notar precisamente porque no flexiona.</sup>

Comment: This one is the correct answer

Comment: Perfecto! No quería mencionar que tenía algo que ver algo con el pasivo para no influenciar las respuestas acá y aún así fue mencionado. Exactamente lo que buscaba, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not an special construction, and that you can not analyse *cosas que*  without the verb before it (in this case *tener*).

The following sentences are equivalent:

```
Tengo reportes que revisar, (tengo) informes que imprimir y (tengo) cartas que redactar
Tengo que revisar reportes, (tengo que) imprimir informes y (tengo que) redactar cartas
```

I guess a correct translation to English could be this:

```
I have log files to review, reports to print and letters to write up
```

I'm trying to find specific references to *sustantivo + que + infinitivo* without success.

Another example of *verbo + sustantivo + que + infinitivo* I come up with:

```
Busco preguntas que responder
```

Grammatically, I guess "preguntas que responder" should be treated as the direct object of "busco", so there must be a name for that compound in Spanish grammar, but I don't know it an I like to find that out, so lets wait for the correct answer.

Edit: Check guifa's answer for the correct one with proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would definitely call it a "special construction".  Tener que, and Hay que, both use this form of `qué` to indicate necessity.  There's no literal way to translate that I know of.  The fact that the verb `tener` is present suggests necessity, like I mentioned.

`Hay qué` on the other hand uses an auxiliary verb, haber, to emphasize the necessity.

```
Hay que mirar esa película
```

vs

```
Tienes que mirar esa película
```

It's safe to say that the `qué` itself emphasizes requirements.

```
Algo de comer
```

vs

```
Algo que comer
```

They each mean the same thing: `Something to eat`, but the second example with the `qué` emphasizes a more necessary action.

I cannot remember for the life of me what this is called.  I've taken several advanced language and liguistics classes in college, but I suppose the knowledge just went away.  I even can remember writing 'perifrasis verbal' as one of my answers on a test, which was of course the right answer, but now I can't even remember what it is exactly.  I had a very clear understanding of it at one point in time, and now it's gone. :(

Hope this helps, because I have no sources.